# I want to show a text file via an iframe but it does not work in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe

I want to show a text file via an iframe but it does not work in IE. It works fine in Mozilla Firefox. Any ideas?

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>   
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/plain; charset=ANSI" />
</head>
<body>

<iframe src='http://localhost/button3.txt'
 scrolling='no' frameborder='0'
 style='border:none; width:1300px; height:500px'></iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

button.txt contains script written in php .Instead of showing the script it executes it.

Comment: If PHP code inside the txt file gets executed, you have a server configuration problem. It has nothing to do with IE in that case. Are you 100% sure that is what happens?

Comment: but it doesnt happen in mozilla

Comment: It works even under old MSIE6. If you're opening the HTML served from a local web server, check the server configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am beginner in PHP.The following answer is based on what i found while searching:

**Set src of IFrame to a PHP file**:

```
<iframe src='http://localhost/showTxt.php' scrolling='no' frameborder='0' style='border:none; width:1300px; height:500px'></iframe>
```

**showTxt.php**:

*1.*

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("test.txt");
?>
```

OR

*2.*

```
<?php
$output=file_get_contents("test.txt");
highlight_string($output);
?>
```